# Incrementar Array com filter

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, ionic3

Preciso incrementar o item `this.order[i].nome_service`na variavel `this.result` somente quando clicar na checkbox, bem como decrementar quando unchecked.

```js
orders = [
{id_service: "1", id_empresa: "9", nome_service: "Servico 01", qtd: "0", checkup: "false", price_service : "250"},

{id_service: "2", id_empresa: "9", nome_service: "Servico 02", qtd: "0", checkup: "false" price_service : "300"},

{id_service: "3", id_empresa: "9", nome_service: "Servico 03", qtd: "0", checkup: "false" price_service : "400"}
]
calc(i) {
  this.orders[i].qtd = (this.orders[i].qtd === "0") ? "1" : "0";

  this.result=this.orders.filter(item => item.qtd === "1").push(this.order[i].nome_service);
  console.log('result '+this.result);

  this.total = this.orders.filter(item => item.qtd === "1").reduce((a, b) => a + parseInt(b.price_service), 0);
  console.log('total = '+this.total);
}
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of orders; let i = index; ">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label class="title">{{item.nome_service}}
      <span>{{item.price_service}}</span>
    </ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox (click)="calc(i)" checked="{{item.checkup}}" color="green"></ion-checkbox>
  </ion-item>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verifique se o item já existe em `result`

```
let test = this.result.filter(item => item === this.orders[i].nome_service);
```

Faça uma condição que verifica se o número de elementos retornados é maior que 0

```
(test.length) ? this.result.splice(this.result.indexOf(this.orders[i].nome_service), 1) : this.result.push(this.orders[i].nome_service);
```

#### Explicação

Caso seja, é porque o item estava marcado, então irá executar o código para remover:

```
this.result.splice(this.result.indexOf(this.orders[i].nome_service), 1)
```

Caso contrário irá adicionar o item em `result`

```
this.result.push(this.orders[i].nome_service)
```

> Veja funcionando em [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-1vquw9?file=pages/home/home.ts)